# .NET application building in release mode in MacOS

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui.mac

I have .NET MAUI application in MacOS, working in Visual Studio 2022. When I'm building it in Debug mode it's working perfectly, but I cannot build it in release mode, I'm getting error.

```
Assets file '/Users/bliink/Documents/BLiiNK/BLiiNK/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-arm64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0-maccatalyst' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'maccatalyst-arm64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. (NETSDK1047)
```

I've tried to play with project configuration but unfortunately I didn't found the right one to compile my application without any error. Can you help me with this and give the hint to how resolve it?

UPD. It's a Mac Catalyst application and here is the list of all NuGet packages:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="5.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui" Version="2.0.0-beta.710" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Localization" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications" Version="7.1.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="PInvoke.User32" Version="0.7.124" />
      <PackageReference Include="Portable.BouncyCastle" Version="1.9.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.141-beta" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="8.0.0-preview.4.23259.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Resources.Extensions" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

UPD2. Here is the error log, which I get when I run the bundle in maccatalyst-arm64 folder after resolving the issue above, like [Alexandar May - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9644964/alexandar-may-msft) suggested.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               TestApp [3684]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Documents/*/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TestApp
Identifier:            com.testapp.TestApp
Version:               2.1.4 (1)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-12-09 17:00:11.4111 +0400
OS Version:            macOS 14.1.2 (23B92)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        64A2D3A6-74FA-1C35-D3DF-AFB84C4D008E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4DB3887F-9027-4B32-A18D-16E0CC7CD222

Time Awake Since Boot: 14000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6387 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  tid_103  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   TestApp [3684]

-----------
Full Report
-----------
{"app_name":"TestApp","timestamp":"2023-12-09 17:00:25.00 +0400","app_version":"2.1.4","slice_uuid":"f7125eac-c00d-32c7-a7d3-6c3fd0b788af","build_version":"1","platform":6,"bundleID":"com.testapp.TestApp","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 14.1.2 (23B92)","roots_installed":0,"name":"TestApp","incident_id":"A0A2B50E-7826-4298-92CA-1BDBF53D8C6F"}
{
  "uptime" : 14000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro18,1",
  "coalitionID" : 3328,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 14.1.2",
    "build" : "23B92",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-12-09 17:00:11.4111 +0400",
  "codeSigningMonitor" : 1,
  "incident" : "A0A2B50E-7826-4298-92CA-1BDBF53D8C6F",
  "pid" : 3684,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-12-09 17:00:03.1434 +0400",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 338575444283,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 338773533538,
  "procName" : "TestApp",
  "procPath" : "\/Users\/USER\/Documents\/*\/TestApp.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/TestApp",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"2.1.4","CFBundleVersion":"1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.testapp.TestApp"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"BE4C2045-5ABA-5E0F-981C-16F2CE6C5EF2","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.testapp.TestApp",
  "crashReporterKey" : "64A2D3A6-74FA-1C35-D3DF-AFB84C4D008E",
  "codeSigningID" : "com.testapp.TestApp",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570425857,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 10,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 4294967295,
  "instructionByteStream" : {"beforePC":"fyMD1f17v6n9AwCRXOD\/l78DAJH9e8Go\/w9f1sADX9YQKYDSARAA1A==","atPC":"AwEAVH8jA9X9e7+p\/QMAkVHg\/5e\/AwCR\/XvBqP8PX9bAA1\/WcAqA0g=="},
  "wakeTime" : 6387,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "4DB3887F-9027-4B32-A18D-16E0CC7CD222",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap: 6","byProc":"TestApp","byPid":3684},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6538444800,
  "size" : 4018896896,
  "uuid" : "6d1aeeac-d56f-3513-9ae1-3894fde828f3"
},
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "name" : "tid_103",
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "b3a666d970e84e599ac2fea6bb49e737b4caa5de",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "6112d17137f5d11121dcd4e2",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000464
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60186475825c62000ccf5450",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000068
    }
  ]
}
}
Model: MacBookPro18,1, BootROM 10151.41.12, proc 10:8:2 processors, 16 GB, SMC
Graphics: Apple M1 Pro, Apple M1 Pro, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 3456 x 2234 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR5, Hynix
```

Comment: 1. Is it a Mac Catalyst App? 2. According to the error log, can you help add  `<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-maccatalyst'))">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>`   to the csproj file? 3. What nuget packages have you installed?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my question with adding the answers to your question. Hope it helps you give me the solution of my problem.

Comment: Have you tried to add `<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-maccatalyst'))">         <RuntimeIdentifier>maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>     </PropertyGroup>` to the csproj file?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! After your suggestion with adding new PropertyGroup, the project was built in Release mode. But I have several questions.

Comment: Before adding this group when this project was built in Debug mode the maccatalyst-x64 subfolder was created in Debug folder with application executable bundle. Now I have 2 subfolders in Release folder maccatalyst-x64 and maccatalyst-arm64. In both of them there are bundle, but in maccatalyst-arm64 it brings me errors on executing, in maccatalyst-x64 works good, but there are no appicon on it, just a white icon. Here is my icon in project file: <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="White" />

Comment: Maybe I should add some property for it? And the last question. At the end of all development process I want to create installation package on this, which bundle I should use? Actually I have big experience in Windows developing, but I'm new in MacOS, so maybe I'm asking very primitive questions, sorry for that.

Comment: Since add the new PropertyGroup can resolve the issue when building in Release mode, I'll post it as an answer. You said in maccatalyst-arm64 it brings me errors on executing, what error? Can you help show the error log?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your question in comment about log file. Actually this not works for me, so if this log can help you to clarify the problem for me, I'll be very appreciated. I've added the cutted log (I cannot paste full report on because there is length restriction) in initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue when building the .NET MAUI application in release mode, you can add the property group listed below to your csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-maccatalyst'))"> 
        <RuntimeIdentifier>maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>     
</PropertyGroup>
```